# OpenMP parallel code is slower than serial

Tags: c++, performance, openmp

***UPD***: Having sorted out the problem in the comments, I've updated the information below, which probably guarantees a solution to the problem.

I want to get high-performance code using the OpenMP standard when working with an object of the contiguous2DVector class, which describes a continuous two-dimensional vector.

1. My primary operating system is Windows 10;
2. I use Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS running through **VMware Workstation 17 Pro**;
3. CPU: **AMD** Ryzen 7 5800H (16 cores), 16GB RAM (all cores are attributed to the VMware).

The test case was created to fill two objects A and B using sequential code and parallelization mode.

***UPD***: I decided to test the code below in Visual Studio 2019, therefore, in the main code I've replaced the *std::size_t* and *std::ptrdiff_t* types with *int* since OpenMP v2.0 does not support the ability to use them for iterations. In addition, I now assign double values to elements of vectors A and B, so I reduced the N by an order of magnitude.

The code description is given in the main function and is specified below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>

template<typename T>
class contiguous2DVector
{
public:

    /* contiguous2DVector (std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols) : 
    m_rows(rows), m_cols(cols), m_array(std::vector<T>(rows*cols)) {} */

    contiguous2DVector(int rows, int cols) :
        m_rows(rows), m_cols(cols), m_array(rows*cols) {}

    ~contiguous2DVector() {}

    /* T& operator() (std::ptrdiff_t row, std::ptrdiff_t col) {
        return m_array[row*m_cols + col];
    } */

    T& operator() (int row, int col) {
        return m_array[row*m_cols + col];
    }

private:
    /* std::size_t m_rows;
    std::size_t m_cols; */

    int m_rows;
    int m_cols;
    std::vector<T> m_array;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    /* int N = 100000000; */

    int N = 10000000;
    int M = 5;

    contiguous2DVector<double> A(N, M);
    double startA = omp_get_wtime();

    /* for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < M; j++)
            A(i,j) = (i+1)*(j+1) + (j+1) + 2; */

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            A(i, j) = 2.*pow(2., 1.5);
    printf("time (serial) = %f\n\n", omp_get_wtime() - startA);

    contiguous2DVector<double> B(N, M);
    double startB = omp_get_wtime();

    /* #pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < M; j++)
            B(i,j) = (i+1)*(j+1) + (j+1) + 2; */

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            B(i, j) = 2. * pow(2., 1.5);
    printf("time (parallel) = %f\n\n", omp_get_wtime() - startB);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I compile as follows (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS):

```
g++ -O3 -fopenmp test.cpp -o test
```

Conditionally, after 5 runs of the compiled code, I get the following results:

```
time (serial) = 0.039859
time (parallel) = 0.049690
```

Why serial block of code is faster then parallel?

***UPD***:

1. Following the advice from the comments, I decided to test this code on a server with native Linux OS and Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6226R processor and noticed the absence of this problem when compiling via g++. I get the following results (g++, Intel Xeon Gold, 16 cores):

```
time (serial) = 0.048932
time (parallel) = 0.012790
```

2. I also decided to use MSVC on Win10 (Visual Studio 2019) and also noticed the absence of this problem, but **only** after I replaced the *size_t* type with *int* and started assigning double values to array elements (perhaps assigning the *int* type to the *double* type was the reason for the longer running of both serial and parallel modes in Visual Studio). I get the following results (VS2019):

```
time (serial) = 0.221778
time (parallel) = 0.054754
```

However, the result of parallel computing was slightly faster in Ubuntu OS than in Win10.

So AMD and VMware are not really suitable for such calculations (see the comments for a more detailed description of the problem).

Comment: I expect a good compiler to optimize out the two main loops because `A` and `B` are not read. Doing this optimization is harder with multiple threads. Do you get the same behaviour if you read A and B after the measurements? You can compute a checksum for example. Also, do you get the same timings if you change the order of the loops? If the loops are not optimized out, the timing should be bound by *page-faults* (i.e. OS-bound). On which OS do you run this code?

Comment: Which hardware (in particular which CPU) is it running on?

Comment: @PierU, AMD Ryzen 7 5800H, 16GB RAM

Comment: Try with 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 threads. For very simple computations like this one, the speed-up may tend to quickly be capped with the number of threads, and too many threads can even result in some slow-down (in short, at some point the threads compete to access the memory).

Comment: @JérômeRichard,
1) Yes, calculating the checksum in parallel mode using reduction(+:sum) turned out to be 6-7 times faster;
2) If I reduce N by 10 times and increase M by 10 times, I notice that sometimes the parallel code fragment is still faster than the sequential one (or at least also in time). But most often the situation remains the same;
3) Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the additional informations. Your processor, like most AMD ones, is subject to NUMA effects. You can try to use `numactl --interleave=all ./your_program` to force pages to be interleaved between multiple nodes. `--touch` may also be interesting to test here. For the reduction, it is normal it is faster : writing in huge arrays the first time is slow due to *page faults* (if `std::vector` do not perform a first-touch) and also because writing in RAM is much slower than reading it (on x86-64). However, it should scale a bit on Linux unless the RAM is saturated in sequential.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, Thanks for the detailed description of the possible problem. However, the additional command `numactl --interleave=all ./test` had no impact. I will write about `--touch` effect later, if I figure out about this key.

Comment: Ok, sad. AFAIK, `--touch` is to perform page pre-faults so to know if the problem comes from a bad scalability of the parallel OS page faults. Can you share information about your memory configuration so we can know if the results are close/far from the optimal timings? You can get this using the one-line command: `sudo dmidecode -t memory | grep -E "^Memory|^\s(Speed|Rank|Bank Locator|Type|Size):"` for example.

Comment: @JérômeRichard,
Memory Controller Information:
Memory Module Information:
1) Type: EDO DIMM (x9);
2) Type: DIMM (x6).
Memory Device:
1) Size: 8 GB/4 GB/2 GB/1 GB/256 MB/128 MB/32 MB/16 MB/8 MB, Bank Locator: RAM slot #0-8, Type: DRAM, Speed: Unknown, Rank: Unknown;
2) Size: No Module Installed, Bank Locator: RAM slot #9-63, Type: DRAM, Speed: Unknown, Rank: Unknown;
3) Size: No Module Installed, Bank Locator: NVD #0-63, Type: Other, Speed: Unknown, Rank: Unknown.
In addition to that, I use VMware Workstation.

Comment: The provided information about memory seem weird and not useful unfortunately. It is certainly because of the virtualization. In fact, I think the VM can be responsible for the reported issue. Some VM introduce huge overheads in multi-threading codes. Sometimes they serialize all threads so the code actually runs serially on the host machine. This is dependent of the VM configuration and the kind of VM. IDK for VMware. I remember the default config for VirtualBox was very bad for parallel codes for example.

Comment: More generally, it is generally not a good idea to analyze performance on VM. Indeed, they are not representative of what is going on on bare metal machines (different behavior resulting in misleading optimization strategies). Moreover, Profiling is more difficult (difficult to access hardware counter). Not to mention there are also often additional issues due to the underlying implementation with is sometimes not even published by the VM vendor. Can you test that on bare metal?

Comment: If this is a VM, how many cores are attributed to the VM?

Comment: @JérômeRichard,
I tried compiling this code on a Linux server with Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6226R (NUMA nodes = 2), CPUs = 30, using g++ (11.3.0, openfoam.com) [`g++ -O3 -fopenmp test.cpp -o test`] and icpc ((ICC), 19.0.5.281 20190815) [`icpc -O3 -qopenmp test.cpp -o test`]:
1) g++: (a) time (serial) = 0.047509; (b) time (parallel) = 0.014067;
2) icpc: (a) time (serial) = 0.125334; (b) time (parallel) = 0.034559.

Comment: @JérômeRichard,
I also tried this on native Win10 OS (with AMD Ryzen 7 5800H) via Visual Studio 2019 [`Microsoft C++ Compiler`] and separately using Intel Compiler 19.1 Update 3 Intel(R) 64 [`icl -O3 -Qopenmp test.cpp -o test`]:
(1) MSVC2019: (a) time (serial) = 0.043200; (b) time (parallel) = 0.045196 (but sometimes the opposite behaviour is observed: (a) time (serial) = 0.050018; (b) time (parallel) = 0.044122);
(2) icl: (a) time (serial) = 0.463310; (b) time (parallel) = 0.505723.

Comment: @PierU, I set all 16 CPUs (logical cores)

Comment: Have you tested compared the OpenMP performance with 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 threads? This is a very important test.

Comment: @PierU, I apologise for the wait. Serial/parallel results:
1) _1 thread_: 0.417607/0.505981;
2) _2 threads_: 0.421725/0.501301;
3) _4 threads_: 0.420096/0.535654;
4) _8 threads_: 0.431512/0.531490;
5) _16 threads_: 0.439084/0.514246.

Comment: Your timings are surprisingly constant with the number of threads, as if your code was using a single thread in all cases. Could you print the value of `omp_get_num_threads()` from within a parallel region?

Comment: @PierU, Of course, I have checked results of this function. I set `omp_set_num_threads(8);` before `#pragma omp parallel {  #pragma omp single { printf("omp_get_num_threads() = %d\n", omp_get_num_threads()); } #pragma omp for "....code....." }`. And I get _omp_get_num_threads() = 8_. It also works with a different number of threads.

Comment: So, you are observing a speed-up if you compile and run on a native Linux machine, but not on a native Windows machine and not on a Linux VM inside a Windows host. Am I correct?

Comment: @PierU, Yes, but after some tweaks. I have updated the main text, thx a lot

Comment: Regarding your updates: assigning an int to a double is fine, there's an automatic cast anyway. MSVC is using an outdate OpenMP specifications, which indeed doesn't handle the `size_t` type as iterator for the parallelized loops. At the end it looks like your VM doesn't handle well the multithreading.

Comment: @PierU, I also re-tested the execution of the updated code (using g++) on an **Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6226R** Linux server, **16 cores** (without VMware), and got a very good result of `time (parallel) = 0.012790`. I think the code also suffers due to AMD's NUMA effects mentioned above.

Comment: AFAIK, your vector prefill memory with zeros causing pages to be bound to one specific NUMA node because of the first-touch policy which is generally the default one. However, `numactl` should have fixed that. You can try not to use a vector but a basic arrays and not fill it (be careful to page fault though in the benchmark). One way to find out what is the exact issue is to check *hardware performance counters*. AFAIK, AMD should have such performance counters for remote accesses to other NUMA nodes (like Intel does).

Comment: By the way, I advise you not to use MSVC if you care about performance. It tends not to optimize codes very well. For example, it tends to vectorize codes less often then Clang and GCC does and tends not to unroll loops either (GCC also tends not to do it unfortunately). The problem with the `size_t` vs `int` is typically a problem with vectorization. There was a similar issue in GCC several years ago but it was a performance bug (and AFAIK it has been fixed since). It is often good to check the assembly code so to see if the compiler produce a pretty good code or not.